# AngularJs prevent full page reload when transitionTo nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to reload a single nested view but it reload the full page.

Here is my state provider :

```
$stateProvider
            .state('connected',{
            views: {
              'friendsList': {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/php/connectedFriendsList.php',
                    controller: 'friendsListController'
              },
              'statusTextInput': {

                    templateUrl: '/angular/php/statusTextInput.php',
                    controller: 'statusTextInputController'
              },
            }   
          })
          .state('connected.refresh',{
          parent: 'connected',
          views: {
                'status@': {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/php/status.php',
                    controller: 'statusController'
                },
            }                
          })
```

And here is my function tu refresh "connected.refresh" :

```
refresh: function(){
                $templateCache.remove('/angular/php/status.php');
                $state.transitionTo('connected.refresh', {}, { reload: 'connected.refresh', inherit: true, notify: true});
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `reload: true` on state level, or use $state.reload()

Comment: Yes I tried,and it doesn't change anything

Comment: try to use this:   $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});

Comment: Hmm the $state.current causes an error : "Cannot transition to abstract state '[object Object]'"